# IIS 6 with wildcard mapping and UNC virtual directory problem

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-6, virtual-directory, unc

On our production servers (win 2003 with IIS6 and load balanced with an F5 BIGIP), we have a problem when introducing wildcardmapping on IIS6. We use .net Framework 3.5 SP1.

The issue manifests itself as by the server only sometimes serving the images stored on a virtual directory pointing to a UNC path.
Sometimes the images are displayed, and sometimes not. Removing the wildcard mapping solved this problem.

I will need wildcard mapping on the server for future features, so any help/pointers to if this is a known problem will be very helpful.

In advance, thanks for any help.

Edit:
The exception it fails with is the following:

> Message: Failed to start monitoring
>   changes to
>   '\ourFileServer\folder1\thumbnails'
>   because the network BIOS command limit
>   has been reached. For more information
>   on this error, please refer to
>   Microsoft knowledge base article
>   810886. Hosting on a UNC share is not supported for the Windows XP Platform.
>   Source: System.Web Data:
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSizeVoid
>   .ctor(System.Web.DirectoryMonitor,
>   System.String, Boolean, UInt32)
>   StackTrace   at
>   System.Web.DirMonCompletion..ctor(DirectoryMonitor
>   dirMon, String dir, Boolean
>   watchSubtree, UInt32 notifyFilter)
>   at
>   System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.StartMonitoring()
>   at
>   System.Web.DirectoryMonitor.StartMonitoringFile(String
>   file, FileChangeEventHandler callback,
>   String alias)    at
>   System.Web.FileChangesMonitor.StartMonitoringFile(String
>   alias, FileChangeEventHandler
>   callback)    at
>   System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.StartMonitoringStreamForChanges(String
>   streamName, StreamChangeCallback
>   callback)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.MonitorStream(String
>   configKey, String configSource, String
>   streamname)    at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question. We have now been able to diagnose the problem. In a nutshell, it seems that once you enable wildcard mapping on UNC shares, ASP.net adds file monitors for each subdirectory. In our case, it's a lot of subdirectories. See [http://weblogs.asp.net/hosterposter/archive/2006/10/30/Hosting-IIS-with-UNC-content-*2D00*-Network-BIOS-commands-and-other-errors.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/hosterposter/archive/2006/10/30/Hosting-IIS-with-UNC-content-_2D00_-Network-BIOS-commands-and-other-errors.aspx).

We will try and fix this by experimenting with different suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

We recently implemented wildcard mapping for our ASP.NET 1.1 application on a Windows 2003 server and it worked fine until we found that a situation similar to yours where a sub-directory (virtual directory) points to a UNC share generates the same error you have mentiojned.

Removing the wildcard mapping solves the problem but we need the wildcard mapping. So if you have found a solution to your problem, we'll be glad to know about it.

Comment: Basically what we had to do was turning off fcn. Turning of File Change Notification will prevent IIS from checking web applications folder and subfolders. Once FCN is monitoring 49+ folders/subfolders, you get this kind of issue. The only downside to disabling FCN is that IIS will not be able to monitor changes to files such as ASP.Net pages, web.config etc. So if you change it, you actually need to do an IISRESET, but for us this wasnt a big issue anyway.Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you have the option "Verify that file exists" turned on for your wildcard application map.  If this setting is checked, try shutting it off and seeing if that resolves the problem.

Comment: This setting is unchecked (never been turned off).

Answer (score 0):

I made a very detailed answer to this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20710473/705198

That answer is an accumulation of all the technet, msdn, and blog reference material I could find on the subject, and what we ended up having to do to fix the problem.