# Setup IIS 6 to only server static files from virtual directories

Tags: asp.net, iis, load-balancing

We're having the same setup and receiving the same problem as:
[IIS 6 with wildcard mapping and UNC virtual directory problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713025/iis-6-with-wildcard-mapping-and-unc-virtual-directory-problem)

**Setup**

- Server 2003 32bit, IIS 6
- ASP.NET wild card mapping
- A virtual directory mapped to an UNC share serving **static** images for a CMS in a load balancing environment

My question if it's possible to turn off asp.net from virtual and only serve static files e.g. images in the virtual directory, to avoid the problem with too many open connections?

If it's not possible I'll guess I have to implement a solution like [Version control of uploaded images to file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862847/version-control-of-uploaded-images-to-file-system) to server the files from a local disc.

I found a possible solution at http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/ that removes the wild card mapping and makes it possible to turn of execution of asp.net files.

Comment: sys admin type questions are more appropriate to serverfault.com.

Comment: Well I think this is appropriate to stackoverflow since it's related to asp.net and the solution of the problem might have implications at the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to remove .NET from a subdirectory as it is part of an application at this point (your root directory).  However, this method works just fine for keeping .NET from processing your static content.

From your site that you linked:

*Alternative*

*If you don’t like to use adsutil.vbs, you can achieve the same by exploiting what appears to be a bug in IIS Manager. Turn your subdirectory into an application (from its Directory tab, click “Create”). Then edit its script mappings to remove aspnet_isapi.dll. Then go back and “Remove” the application you just created. The metabase’s new ScriptMaps value will be retained, even though the option has now disappeared from the GUI.*

Comment: +1 I'd never noticed that if you configure a mapping at the site level, it effectively copies these mappings to the virtual roots below allowing you to vary them individually. Nice one!